# AEM 6.3: Bad Request when replacing dot in selector for slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, aem, dispatcher

I am trying to make my product details page have the following format:

```
https://stage.aemsite.com/en/product-details/some-product
```

We use selectors for our product details so I understand AEM won't be able to interpret this, my idea was to use the dispatcher to allow a passthrough to the correct format `https://stage.aemsite.com/en/product-details.some-product`, but this is resulting in a bad request.

I tested this on https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/ and it should technically work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/product-details/([^?]*)(/?)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1/product-details.%2 [PT,L,NC]
```

Any idea?

EDIT: As per the correct answer this was the format that worked for me, the reason being that AEM needs the path to be the path to the resource inside the content tree.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/product-details/([^?]*?)/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/content/marketplace/$1/product-details.$2 [L]
```

Comment: Could you please do mention url `https://stage.aemsite.com/en/product-details.some-product` should be served by which file or url in backend? Kindly clarify once.

Comment: AEM has a dispatcher file (stage.conf), in that file I wrote the rules for the passthrough, does that help? As for the architecture AEM is based on a Sling model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tested this on `https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/` and it should technically work.

FWIW, that tool looks wrong IMO. (I think it's ignoring the `PT` flag?)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/product-details/([^?]*)(/?)$
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1/product-details.%2 [PT,L,NC]
> ```

The "400 Bad Request" is most certainly due to using the `PT` (passthrough) flag with an absolute URL. You should not be using an absolute URL here (unless you want to trigger an external redirect or proxy the request) and the `PT` flag is then not required in a `.htaccess` context, since this is the default action.

The trailing part of your regex `([^?]*)(/?)$`, is arguably incorrect. It looks like you are trying to omit an optional trailing slash from the first captured subpattern. However, that is not what this regex does. Because the preceding quantifier (`*`) is greedy, this will also consume the optional trailing slash, so the `/?` that follows doesn't actually do anything. The regex `([^?]*)(/?)$` is the same as `([^?]*)$`. (It's also unlikely that you have a %-encoded `?` in the URL-path, so this is probably the same as `(.*)`.) If you wanted to exclude an optional trailing slash from being captured, you would need to make the preceding pattern non-greedy, so that it doesn't consume the *optional* trailing slash. eg. `([^?]*?)/?$` (the capturing group at the end would seem to be superfluous). Or, use *alternation*, eg. `([^?]*)(?:/|)$`. Or, make the preceding pattern more restrictive, so it won't match a slash. eg. `^([\w-]*)/?$`. (Side note: making the trailing slash optional here, potentially creates a duplicate content issue.)

You also don't need the `RewriteCond` directive, as this check can be performed (more efficiently) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` does not apply to the condition anyway, so this flag is superfluous in the rule you posted. However, it would only serve to promote duplicate content.

So, taking the above points into consideration would result in the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/product-details/([^?]*?)/?$ $1/product-details.$2 [L]
```

HOWEVER, whether this works or not with AEM (or any CMS) is another matter, since AEM probably only "sees" the requested URL that contains a *slash*. The rewritten URL containing a dot is mostly hidden from the backend script unless it is expected and knows where to look. When the URL is rewritten like this, Apache sets the `REDIRECT_URL` server variable to the rewritten URL, but a CMS is unlikely to check this since it's not necessarily the URL being requested.

The order of these directives in `.htaccess` is also important. Presumably you have a front-controller pattern later in the file that routes the request?

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! I managed to access the dispatcher's logs and I found the following error: [core:error] [pid 20651:tid 139675540870912] [client 10.73.0.60:44460] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /en/product-details/some-product HTTP/1.1 I think AEM expects the URL to be relative, my page actually lives in /content/mysite/en/product-details.some-product.html

Comment: I'll update my question with the correct rewrite based on your amazing explanation. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. That "error" would seem to be the Apache error associated with the "400 Bad Request". The "URL" stated is the contents of the `Host` header on the initial request, not the URI that is being rewritten to, which is probably what's causing that error. "the correct rewrite" - But the directive you posted presumably results in a 302 external redirect (so just changes the URL back)?

Comment: I ended up using this to prevent a 302 and instead keep the formatted URL on the browser: RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/product-details/([^?]*?)/?$ /content/marketplace/$1/product-details.$2.html [PT,L] this satisfies all the requirements :)

Comment: The `PT` flag is not required if this is in `.htaccess`.

Comment: When I remove it we get an AEM error, it may have to do with how the dispatcher works